# When trying to pass in a post it is not working

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
class Post(CreateView):
    fields = ("title","about","itempicture")
    template_name = "post.html"
    model = models.Listing
```

I can't seem to figure out why is is not working my html and views connect perfectly put when try to send in a post request it does not work I would happy if someone could help me out

Comment: Did you define a form in a forms.py file?

Comment: I believe you don't need one as it is a class based view

Comment: Is the form displayed in your template? Even though you didn't define it anywhere in your code?

Comment: yes the form is displayed in my template the issue I am getting is a This Field Is required

Comment: OK. In this case try to change the field in your models.py with the `null=True`. In this case, the field you are not inserting in the form, shouldn't be required anymore

Answer (score 1):

You should define your form in the view:

```
class Post(CreateView):
    fields = ("title","about","itempicture")
    template_name = "post.html"
    model = models.Listing
    form_class = YourForm
```